# IntelPIN：How to get app params after "--"

Tags: c++, instrumentation, intel-pin

Hi does anyone know how to get app params after "--"? So for example if I have something like:
`pin -t MyTool -- somebinary input`

How do I get the string "somebinary input" in MyTool. I checked the documentation but there doesn't seem to be anything I can use, or maybe I've overlooked something? Thanks.

I use the API KNOB_BASE::StringLongAll() to print all, but I didn't find the command params after "--"

Comment: `int main(int argc, char** argv) { vector args(argv+1, argv+argc); for (auto const& arg : args) { if (arg == "--") cout << "Found it!\n"; }}`

Comment: it’s doesn't work. The 'argv' in main() of Mytool.cpp only contains the params before "--", it seems pintools filter the params.